# Use multiple Database Tables in single model in Lumen Framework

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have these Database tables:

```
country_US
country_FR
country_EN
country_NL
country_ES
```

How can I create a single model for above tables? Database structure of all these tables are the same.

What can be the workaround for this scenario in Lumen Framework?

Comment: if the structure is identical why are they separate tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for having such a bad database design. The ideal would be to have only one table with a 'language' column.

Anyway, one dirty way would be to overwrite the [getTable()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1891) method:

```
/**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if ($conditionUS)
        return 'country_US';


    if ($conditionFR)
        return 'country_FR';

    // etc ...

}
```

The the [getTable()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1891) method is the method that Laravel intenally uses to determine the table that should use for a model. If you override it, you take control of which table will be used.

Comment: What is getTable and what is $conditionUS? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: I've updated my anser to explain what is the getTable() method. $conditionUS, $conditionFR,... are abstract conditions that have to be matched for each table to be used. I cannot  give you more information about those since you are the one who decide to use more than one table per model, so you are the one who nows the reasons